# @InverseBindingAdapter with parameters

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

I have binding adapter that set editText to values 0-99. But I wish to set this params from the layout, how can I do this?

```
app:rangeFixer="@={viewModel.times}"

@BindingAdapter("app:rangeFixer")
fun AppCompatEditText.rangeFixer(value: String) {
setSelection(text.toString().length)
if (text.toString() == value) {
    return
}
setText(value)

}

@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "app:rangeFixer", event = 
"android:textAttrChanged")
fun AppCompatEditText.rangeFixer(): String {
var ret = ""
    //1 and 99 set from layout
text.toString().toIntOrNull()?.let {
    ret = if (it < 1) "1"
    else if (it > 99) "99"
    else text.toString()
}
return ret

}
```

Comment: is your times variable in viewmodel is declared  val? if it is ,, change it to var to enable two way binding.

Comment: I wish to numbers min and max could be set from layout and sent as variables to rangeFixer

Comment: I guess, you need to make a custom view for that.